# OnItemClick() para varias views en un ListView

Tags: android, listview

Tengo un `ListView` personalizado dentro de un fragmento, que coge los datos de un `CursorAdapter`. En cada fila del `ListView` hay varios `TextView`, un `ImageView` (un cuadro de verificación) y un botón.

Lo que quiero es atender los clicks de cada *view* de forma independiente: El `ImageView` (al hacer click se invertirá su posición de marcado/desmarcado), el botón y los `TextViews` (se abrirá otro fragmento para editar los campos).

Para el botón, no hay problema: Pongo un `setOnClickListener` dentro del `CursorAdapter` y listo.

Se supone que el resto podría manejarlos desde el fragmento con:

```
mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        long viewId = v.getId();
        ...
}
```

Pero `viewId` solo devuelve el `RelativeLayout` que uso para el `ListView`.

He visto [este artículo](http://www.migapro.com/click-events-listview-gridview/), donde lo resuelve fácilmente: Poner esto en el `getView` del adaptador:

```
viewHolder.button1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
viewHolder.button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
    }
});
```

Pero yo no tengo un `getView`, ya que estoy usando un `CursorAdapter`, y en el `bindView` no sé la forma de conseguir una referencia al `Listview` para usar el `performItemClick`.

Comment: pero el CursorAdapter extiende de  BaseAdapter y sí tienes `getView()`...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)

Comment: Si lo tienes, pero he leído que lo correcto al usar un CursorAdapter es usar sólo newView y bindView (getView implementa métodos que ya trae CursorAdapter).

Comment: intentaste ya o tienes posibilidad de cambiar a un RecyclerView?

Comment: Si, es el próximo paso, pero es un reto conseguirlo con ListView. ¡Gracias, Chisko!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Una luz! El problema era poder usar el "performItemClick" desde bindView. Con ello, podría manejar el evento desde el fragmento. Y para ello, necesito una referencia al ListView, lo que he logrado añadiendo esto en el bindView del adaptador:

```
imgCheck.setTag(cur.getPosition());
imgCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View parent = (View) v.getParent();
        ListView lvCheck = (ListView) parent.getParent();
        lvCheck.performItemClick(v, pos, 0);
    }
});
```

La idea viene del artículo http://jmsliu.com/2444/click-button-in-listview-and-get-item-position.html

¡Llevaba ya unas horitas con esto!